# Server side android process

Tags: java, android, server

I have a massive java code that doing allot processing in my android app. this takes time and memory usage.

I want to add an option in my app for server side processing, and also
use the services from my website.

I thought to separate my processing code to an android library (Must be android due to many library usage) and re-use it in the server.

I've read some articles but found nothing that i can say, Yes I can do it.

Can I create a java server that provide web services using android dependencies ?

Comment: I'm not an authority on Android, though i don't believe android is modular enough for you to take parts of it as libraries.  I may well be wrong. 

Saying that, surely the work you are wanting to delegate to the server is generic enough?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: you want to create a http web server on your android device? am I right?

Comment: I am doing video and audio processing. I would disconnect my code from android but it is allot of work. and encoding.. I know that i can use also `ffmpeg` but i'm trying to minimize my work, and second re-use my code. I've found this http://www.donnfelker.com/setting-up-an-android-build-server-part-3-installing-the-android-sdk/ article.. but i still want to get final approval form someone who did it

Comment: You got me wrong @ErfanMowlaei. The services will run on the (java) server and will use my android libraries (which of course including android dependencies).